# Python Development Mode: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxxx

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, setup.py, pypi

i have a project in python that works just fine if call it by "python do.py", but when i install it in Development Mode and the script imports my modules i get a "ModuleNotFoundError". This is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


with open('README.rst') as f:
    readme = f.read()

with open('LICENSE') as f:
    license = f.read()

setup(
    name='do-pack',
    version='0.1dev',
    description='A command-line tool to create python packages',
    long_description=readme,
    author='Carlos Montecinos Geisse',
    author_email='carlos.w.montecinos@gmail.com',
    url='https://github.com/wilfredinni/do-pack',
    license=license,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['click'],
    python_requires='>=3',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'do = do.do:main',
        ]
    },
)
```

This is the structure (main and modules are in do/):

[tree][1]

This is the call when i use python do.py:

```
(python-cli) λ python do.py
Usage: do.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Simple CLI based script to make your Repository Structure.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  assistant  A step by step assistant.
  create     creates an empty proyect structure.
```

and, this is the output when i run it in development mode:

```
(python-cli) λ do
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carlo\Envs\python-cli\Scripts\do-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('do-pack', 'console_scripts', 'do')()
  File "c:\users\carlo\envs\python-cli\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\carlo\envs\python-cli\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\carlo\envs\python-cli\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2408, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\carlo\envs\python-cli\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2414, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\dropbox\dropbox\projects\python\do-pack\do\do.py", line 3, in <module>
    import skeleton
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skeleton'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please create [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your failing code. Btw your `setup.py` seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the `do` folder has an `__init__.py` file inside.
   <strike>2. Add 'do' to the `packages=` kwarg in your setup.py</strike>
   Looks like you are handling that ok with `find_packages()`

## Working Example

```
+ app
|+ do
 |+ __init__.py
 |+ do.py
```

#### setup.py

from setuptools import setup

```
setup(
    name="cliapp",
    version='0.1',
    packages=['do'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        do=do.do:run
    ''',
)
```

#### do.py

```
def run():
    print('Completed')
```

#### From app/ folder, install and run:

```
>>> pip install .
>>> do
Completed
```

## Update

---

I ran your code locally and looks like it might just be a python relative/absolute import issues inside your code.

If you use full absolute imports it should work:

#### do.py

Instead of

```
import skeleton
import licenses
import setup_config
```

You need to use absolute or relative package imports

```
# Absolute
from do import skeleton
from do import licenses
from do import setup_config

# Relative
from . import skeleton
from . import licenses
from . import setup_config
```

Comment: there is a __init__.py inside. This is the github repository https://github.com/wilfredinni/do-pack and the module tha is not found is "skeleton" or any other inside do/

Comment: Just saw you were using find_packages() that should be fine as well.
I cloned your repo and it's working fine here. You just need to use full absolute imports or relative imports:
http://prntscr.com/iglmr1
`from do

Comment: thaks, now it works perfect! its my first project so its really helpfull

Comment: Awesome looks like you are doing well, so congrats
Please be sure to accept the answer if your issue was resolved.